# AngularJS $resource not sending X-Requested-With

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm using angular 1.1.5 and I'm using a $resource to make a XHR to a REST service but it seems like the the $resource isn't appending the header as X-Requested-With as XMLHttpRequest, **is that a normal behavior?** and Do I need to append the header manually?

```
function loginCtrl($scope,$resource) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
         var resource = $resource('/Api/User/login', {},
              {
                  authenticate: {
                      method: 'POST',
                      isArray: false,
                      headers: {
                          '__RequestVerificationToken':  $scope.loginRequest.Token

                      }
                  }
              });
         resource.authenticate($scope.loginRequest);
    };
}
```

Comment: $resource doesn't support headers. you may need to switch to use $http

Comment: it does, I think since version 1.1.3

Comment: I think you still have to set it in $http, something like $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

Comment: actually I can to add the header manually like headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'} and it works but why it doesn't sending it by default.

Comment: Was wondering the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19001632/33453

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Just add this to your app

```
myAppModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

Comment: Laravel 5.1 expect this header to determine a request as an “ajax request”.

Comment: great, now, how do we do that in Angular2?

Comment: I've been looking for almost a week, and right when I commented, I found the answer :/ https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/BaseRequestOptions-class.html

Comment: You need this, in order for Asp.Net MVC to recognize correctly `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`

Comment: @Ayyash new link?

Comment: @Jeff https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/BaseRequestOptions-class.html

Answer (score 26):

It used to but was changed. [(see here)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d)

"X-Requested-With header is rarely used in practice and by using
it all the time we are triggering preflight checks for crossdomain
requests."

From Thomas Pons' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001632/33453).

Comment: it's good to know, I'm using it because I'm validating the request with an antiForgeryToken attribute in servicestack, the thing is that I validate to be an ajax request to know that at least that request was made from a form, now the question is: "how can I know in the server side if that request is ajax?", thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'd give you a +1 for the additional reference to the actual commit.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it using:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

Also you can set the header to accept `application/json`:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl',
  headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
})
```