# checking if the request is xhr or http from rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `get` route like below in my routes. How can I check if the request is a xhr or normal http request?

What I want to do is a redirect if its `http` and if `xhr` it will go to below `controller` and `action`

```
#if xhr
get '/search' => 'pages#search'

#if http
get '/search' => redirect("/")
```

how can I do this from `routes.rb`???

**As per BoraMa's answer here is the routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'

  devise_for :users,
             :path => '',
             :path_names => {:edit => 'profile'},
             :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
  resource :pages, only: [:edit] do
    collection do
      patch 'update_password'
    end
  end

  resources :conversations, only: [:create, :index] do
    resources :messages, only: [:create, :index]
  end

  resources :notifications do
    collection do
      post :mark_as_read
    end
  end


  root 'pages#home'
  get '/general' => 'pages#general'
  get '/drafts' => 'rooms#drafts'
  get '/active' => 'rooms#active_listings'
  get '/inactive' => 'rooms#inactive_listings'
  get '/search', to: 'pages#search',
      constraints: lambda { |request| request.xhr? }

  get '/search', to: redirect("/"),
      constraints: lambda { |request| !request.xhr? }

  get '/change_password' => 'pages#change_password'
  # get ':page' => 'pages#show'


  resources :rooms do
    post :make_active
    post :make_inactive
    resources :photos, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
  end

  mount ImageUploader.direct_endpoint, at: "/attachments/images"

end
```

**chrome console request header**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/search.json?latitude=12.9715987&longitude=77.59456269999998
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:88
Content-Type:text/html
Location:http://localhost:3000/
X-Request-Id:5686e56f-07af-44f5-a1a3-518bb47b513c
X-Runtime:0.006135
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_deploy_test_session=L3IwZUxYNVRITGpPYlE1OHZoMmFVdHJqRjRlRGpKb2xDaEhWTzNjZ0RkY01nNGVjeUlZVUlHckN3L0FGcTZuVXp6ckF0a1R6ZEt5alJzZ3VPcjFVNWdqZjJUeG1DaVhXNXlXaGhwVWd2UHF4NldYMzYxU0oxeVRmZFV5UTk1YUJHZnF3WTVNa0FuVWcwZFdqN1dUMXh3PT0tLVZ0Q0FqSkNXYmtKL25HRHJzWC9VOFE9PQ%3D%3D--7cfd795484ed3f9139e850399405698e0a33e308; XSRF-TOKEN=JBQC%2BanEl82RonPiLTdzSIMjkbtItgavnYtaYdIQ15MFXBVNUDS7gP5pxLkWV3zwagKypjcV23J2soOLdxhvtQ%3D%3D; _roomduck_session=ZjVhalZIdW9Ma2NZNnJ5cHIxY3hudDhCRFpBT1pwWEc5WjN2TkxzcEZaQTVYZ0RpUzBEVTFVWWFxbGJ5NTVkRWNJcDF6Qkg0dFRicVIwYTlCSG5WcDEvSXZ6aW9ZcUNzL0lPaGpRbUg5Z3dJVE1GcnQxSWo0V1hZOG9OUzNaZmYwQ0wwZ3k2M0xMd0RKVWNTK2VWOHVqNm1EQjhvd045dEg5ejRqNEtFWGhYSVN0ZzRpSDR2OU5udFRzOEdKZnBMY3RiVklDdnRGQ0lEbUJsbnhWcENjVlhISHB4dzZtS05XRmpwVndlZUpxdz0tLUhieEJGT0RZdWxaREZrckZyWlRkZnc9PQ%3D%3D--0ad068283b426d9158fe4c74d5abc6e9eab52bb9
Host:localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
X-XSRF-TOKEN:JBQC+anEl82RonPiLTdzSIMjkbtItgavnYtaYdIQ15MFXBVNUDS7gP5pxLkWV3zwagKypjcV23J2soOLdxhvtQ==
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
latitude:12.9715987
longitude:77.59456269999998
```

In the rails server log i can see that the request is going to pages#home which is the root.

Comment: why not to handle this in controller?

Comment: @Nithin using angular on front end and all I needed is a simple redirect..Thought it would be more efficient to do in routes..isn't it possible from routes??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374834/rails-how-to-detect-if-request-was-xhr-inside-routes-rb

Comment: @Nithin so not possible..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using [custom routing constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
get '/search', to: 'pages#search',
  constraints: lambda { |request| request.xhr? }

get '/search', to: redirect("/"),
  constraints: lambda { |request| !request.xhr? }
```

With this setup, Rails will first call the lambda constraint and will route to the given route only if the constraint results in a trueish value.

Comment: it is working for non-xhr routes it is going to "/" but for xhr requests its going to the root controller and action... could you please tell me whats am doing wrong here.. updating the question with full route.rb.. Think its some minor bug..

Comment: Your routes seem correct to me. Are you sure you're actually making a XHR request? I tested it fine with `$.get('/search')` (i.e. in JS, using jQuery).

Comment: am using angular and yes its xhr..It will work fine If I only use `  get '/search' => 'pages#search'`. I am updating the question with the header I got for the request.

Comment: A XHR request must have the [`X-Requested-With` header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220701/rails-detect-if-request-was-ajax) present and I can't see such in your headers listing. Sorry, I'm unable to test with angular right now but it seems that you might need to add the header to angular yourself, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168836/angularjs-resource-not-sending-x-requested-with) answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that. Didnt checked it. But seems like you are right as am not setting the headers manually as it worked without that when not using `html5Mode `.  I will try that and update here.. I am accepting this as the answer as it basically answers my question. Thank you for the support...